# NSString and NSUrl not converting properly

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

So I am trying to retrieve data from an XML stream coming from a URL.  This URL is configured on a search string the user inputs.  Is there any reason why this code should not be working?

```
NSString *searchString = "Geoff";

NSString *updatedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mysearchpage.com/searchQuery=%@", searchString];

NSLog(updatedURL);
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:updatedURL];
```

Now this works fine for single word searches, but as soon as I try and search for like a first and last name, the URL returns nil every time.  Is there any behavior with the strings that may be causing that?

I have even tried to replace the " "'s with "%20"'s when the search string was appended to see if that was the problem. I did that using:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[updatedURL stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%%20"]];
```

any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm going to assume that the missing " wasn't your problem, so I added it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use NSString's `-stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method for that:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:
   [updatedURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed a copy & paste of your code, it might be because the `searchString` is missing the `@`-sign. This should be `NSString *searchString = @"Geoff";`

Comment: No it's not a copy and paste, I simplified the URL so it would be easier to understand.  I realize that is missing a bunch of stuff.